# Regex preg_match_all in between a specific function

Tags: php, regex, translation, preg-match-all

I have created a Language class that automatically translate's the string when passed through a function. I am now working on a tool that will allow me to extract all these snippets of text and save them to a file ready to be translated individually, although I am having some trouble matching only the text in between quotes with regex.

Example of html:

```
 <h1><?=$Lang->t("Example text")?></h1>
 <h1><?=$Lang->t("Example (text)")?></h1>
 <h1><?=$Lang->t("Example %s", 'text')?></h1>
```

Example of outputs:

```
Example text
Example (text)
Example %2
```

The parameter passed in the 3rd example should be excluded just like shown in the last example output

Note: This should ignore everything else that might be on any page, javascript, jQuery, Php, etc, etc..

Can anybody shed any light on this please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use what is already done for you? getText

http://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1/

Comment: I am aware of this, my system works in the same way, I just like mine more :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be an expression like this:

```
$re = <<<'re'
    /
        \$Lang->t\(
            (
                " ( (?: \\. | [^"] )* ) "
                |
                ' ( (?: \\. | [^'] )* ) '
            )
    /x
re;
```

Basically, match `$Lang->t(` followed by a single or double quoted string, with respect to escaping. Usage as follows:

```
$code = <<<'eof'
<h1><?=$Lang->t("Example text")?></h1>
<h1><?=$Lang->t("Example (text)")?></h1>
<h1><?=$Lang->t("Example %s", 'text')?></h1>
<h1><?=$Lang->t("Example\"foo\"", 'text')?></h1>
<h1><?=$Lang->t('Example\'foo\'', 'text')?></h1>
eof;

preg_match_all($re, $code, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r(array_map('end', $m));
```

This is not bullet-proof as regular expressions cannot fully parse a programming language, but will work fine in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes that is exactly what I need, I tried your regex (I only want double quotes method) I have tried:  $re = "<<<'re'\$Lang->t\((\" ( (?: \\. | [^\"] )* ) \")/x re;"; but every way i try it, I get php errors, any idea?